# Vector color function varying upon vector direction

Tags: plotting, color, vector

I have the following code:

```
f[l_, p_, r_, \[Phi]_] := (r Sqrt[2])^Abs[l] E^(-r^2) LaguerreL[p, Abs[l],2r^2] E^(-I r^2/2) E^(I l \[Phi]);
L[oam1_, r_, \[Phi]_] := f[oam1, 0, r, \[Phi]] {1, I}/Sqrt[2];
R[oam2_, r_, \[Phi]_] := f[oam2, 0, r, \[Phi]] {1, -I}/Sqrt[2];
cl = 1/Sqrt[2];
cr = 1/Sqrt[2];(*1/Sqrt[2]*)
state[oam1_, \[Theta]_, oam2_, r_, \[Phi]_] := cr*R[oam1, r, \[Phi]] + E^(I \[Theta]) cl*L[oam2, r, \[Phi]];
vvpol = VectorPlot[Evaluate@Re[state[7, Pi, -7, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]]], {x, -1.4,1.4}, {y, -1.4, 1.4},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0.2 < x^2 + y^2 < 1.6],
VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#, #2]/(2 \[Pi])] &), VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False,
Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, VectorScale -> {0.03, 0.95, None}, VectorStyle -> {{Thickness[0.007], Black}}, VectorPoints -> 25]
```

Which produces the following image:

[image]

As you can see the Hue map varies circularly, independently on the vector directions.
What I want to have is a Hue map that varies depending on the direction of the field.

*For instance, all the arrows pointing north will be green and all those pointing south blue and, of course, different color shades from north to south and vice-versa*.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`VectorColorFunction >> Details:`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorColorFunction.html)

[image]

So we can use

```
VectorColorFunction -> (Quiet @ Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 π)] &)
```

to get

[image]

Comment: t is indeed working, thank you! Could you help me to understand it better? I don't think I got the difference between (#,#2) and (#3,#4). What are they precisely doing?

Comment: maybe writing the pure function `func = Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 π)] &`  as `func[x_,y_,vx_,vy_, norm_]:= Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π)]` helps?

Comment: Ah ok, got it! So #3 and #4 states we use the values of the field (vx, vy) in the arctan. Perfect! Thank you to make it clearer :)